# MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table ' ' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django, django-tests

I get the error "MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_sageservice.processed_transactions' doesn't exist")" when ever I try to run the my tests  using the command `pyton manage.py test` .

I have tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`, all goes well but when try running my tests I get the error below
[image]

my tests.py look like this

```
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
class DashboardTests(TestCase):

    def test_uses_dashboard_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'dashboard.html')
```

My settings look like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'sageservice',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'not_my_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your test database needs to be different than your production database. Test databases are destroyed once the test cases are run. In your case the database was not created. You should go through this documentation for detailed information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/

Also make sure you've added app that include `Dashboard` model into the INSTALLED_APPS setting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your [test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) migrations may be in a stuck state. Consider destroying the database when running [`python manage.py test`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#test).